# How do I do substitutions for localised strings in freemarker

Tags: spring, localization, freemarker

I'm using spring and freemarker and have the basics working.

I've got a properties file like

```
help.text=For further information please see the <a href="{0}">help page</a>.
```

I'm currently outputting localised messages using

```
${rc.getMessage("help.text")}
```

However I'm having trouble figuring out how I can pass in my substitution variables. Can you help?

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read the [Spring API documentation about `RequestContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContext.html#getMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.List%29) (your `rc`?) correctly, then

```
${rc.getMessage("help.txt", ["yourHelpUrl"])}
```

might work, because `getMessage` can receive an additional `List` argument with message args, which you can supply via a [FreeMarker sequence](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_seuqence).

Answer (score 2):

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>


<#assign args = ["yourHelpUrl"]>
<@spring.messageArgs "help.txt" args/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do the substitution variables in my Java code somewhere and then dump the fully localized text into a Map where it's accessed by Freemarker like this:

```
${localizedValues["help.txt"]}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are correctly configuring freemarker in the spring MVC context then the right way to do it is:

1. Import the spring macros in the template
2. Use the mensaje macro

`<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />

<@spring.messageText "code", "Default message"/>`

See the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity